# Unable to Install PhoneGap macOS (Desktop App)

Tags: ios, node.js, macos, cordova, phonegap

I downloaded `8.9.4 LTS Node.js for macOS (x64)`.

Then I went to: `http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/desktop/` and followed the instructions.

I had just finished dragging PhoneGap into my applications folder and when I tried to open the application, this popped up:

[image: error message]

The most important detail from the image seems to be:

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/bruce/.config/configstore/insight-phonegap.json' You don't have access to this file." Any help with solving this would be greatly appreciated! (same thing happened when I tried to use the CLI)

Comment: It seems like a permission issue. The electron app is trying to access this file. Can you try to give permission like `sudo chmod 777 /Users/bruce/.config/configstore/insight-phonegap.json`

Comment: @yueyou Thank you for the idea! Here's what happened:
chmod: /Users/bruce/.config/configstore/insight-phonegap.json: No such file or directory Any idea what I should do?

Comment: You may need to reinstall it or try to add a file under that folder. The json file is very simple only has 2 data filed. `{
        "clientId": 201943979718,
        "optOut": true
}`

Comment: @yueyou reinstalling didn't work and I couldn't find the file when I tried to spotlight search for it. So it seems like it's being hidden from me maybe... Should I try it as the root user? Or any other ideas to find this file?

Comment: The file can be find under a hidden folder. You can try to create it as `vim /Users/bruce/.config/configstore/insight-phonegap.json` or try it as a root user will work I think. Because the error message is linking to a permission issue

Comment: If it works let me know I will summarise and post it as it is

Comment: @yueyou Hey, I tried logging in as a new user, not a root user, and it worked! Thank you!!

Comment: Glad I can help you. Posted the answer as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a user permission issue.

User other users (such as root) with privilege to write to  `.config/configstore/` folder can solve the problem